# Access to android usb port from chroot linux?

Tags: android, linux, usb

Is it possible to communicate with the native Android USB port from a chrooted linux system running on top of android? 
(We need to run software that required full linux libraries and these are not available on Android).

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you might get better help on [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) or http://android.stackexchange.com/